# I am trying to scrape images from website and using selenium but getting an error in the code

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My code

```
for idx, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
    imgs = []
    try:
        driver.get(row['listing_url'])
        sleep(10)
        script = "document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-toggle')[0].click();"
        driver.execute_script(script)
        sleep(10)
        scroll_down(driver)
        imgs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//img[@class="i1o0kbi8 i1mla2as i1cqnm0r dir dir-ltr"]')
        imgs = list(set([img.get_attribute('src') for img in imgs]))
    finally:
        os.makedirs('images', exist_ok=True)
        with open(f'images/{row["id"]}_{row["host_id"]}.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(imgs, f)
```

Error

> JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')

What is wrong with my code and what is the correct approach

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-toggle')` isn't finding anything, so there's nothing in the `[0]` element to click on.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')
```

...implies that `click()` method can't be invoked on ***undefined*** element.

---

### This usecase

Possibly the following part of the script:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-toggle')[0]
```

doesn't identifies any element, so remains ***undefined*** and `click()` method can't be invoked on it.

---

### Solution

Try to identify the desired element uniquely within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) using a suitable [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) and execute your code.